# What is the wso2am image root password?

Tags: docker, wso2

Im studing the wso2am [using his docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am). [i'm following the api-manager-developer-fundamentals-tutorial](https://wso2.com/training/api-manager-developer-fundamentals)

In one of the test labs i need to edit the web.xml file, but there is no editor (vi,vim,nano) inside the [wso2am imagem](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am).

When i use the command `docker exec -it api-manager bash` I going into the container but with the wso2 user. So i have no permition to use the apt-get and install an editor.

Someone knows how can i handle this? 
Really thank you

Comment: See the “How to update configurations” section in the image documentation you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebuild image based wso2/wso2am image,like this:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM wso2/wso2am
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vim
```

Build image:
`docker build -t wso2/wso2am:vim .`

Run container:
`docker run -it -p 8280:8280 -p 8243:8243 -p 9443:9443 --name api-manager wso2/wso2am:vim`

Comment: I run your code but i got this error:
`PS C:\git\tt> docker build -t getjv/wso2am:nano .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM wso2/wso2am:2.5.0
 ---> 1bb1263f149a
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nano
 ---> Running in 3cc861ef064a
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nano' returned a non-zero code: 100
PS C:\git\tt>`

Comment: Thanks you, help me found the solution.
In the Docker file i put the instruction  `USER root`   or i can use`docker exec --user="root" -it api-manager bash` from terminal.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I was just testing how to solve your problem.  this Dockerfile is worked :   FROM wso2/wso2am:2.5.0

user root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nano && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

user 802

Comment: 802 is the USERID of USER 'wso2carbon' inside container.

Comment: @JhonatanMorais I think, your comment is the most correct way of gaining required user permissions, when working with `wso2` docker images (and not only, actually!). It deserves to be put in a separate comment and must be approved as the best solution: `docker exec --user=root -it api-manager bash`